# About Symfony 1.4 schema creation for existing project using Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

i am trying to create an application using symfony 1.4 at first i have installed the orange hrm 2.7 version application which was created using symfony frame work now i am creating an schema for new application but in my application i am using the existing table column as the relations in my new application the both applications are in same database i have configured the database.yml as

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=neworangehrm'
      username: root
      password: null
```

and i created my schema as

```
samplepayperiod:
  tableName: samplepayperiod
  columns:
    emp_number:
      name: emp_number 
      type: integer(7)
    periodid:
      name: periodid 
      type: integer(11)
      primary: true
    startdate:
      name: starttime 
      type: date(25)
      default: ''
      notnull: true
    enddate:
      name: endtime 
      type: date(25)
      default: ''
      notnull: true
    locked:
      name: locked 
      type: smallint(5)
      default: ''
  relations:
   Employee:
    onDelete: CASCADE
    foreignAlias: samplepayperiods
```

then i used to run the following command

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\neworangehrm\nohrm>php symfony doctrine:build-model
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     C:\Documents and Settings\Dilli...\Temp/doctrine_schema_56849.yml
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: class in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor
\doctrine\Doctrine\Import\Builder.php on line 684

Notice: Undefined index: class in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doct
rine\Doctrine\Import\Builder.php on line 684
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: alias in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor
\doctrine\Doctrine\Import\Builder.php on line 685

Notice: Undefined index: alias in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doct
rine\Doctrine\Import\Builder.php on line 685
>> tokens    C:/xampp/htdocs/orangehrm/newor...e/Basesamplepayperiod.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> file-     C:/xampp/htdocs/orangehrm/newor.../config/config_autoload.yml.php
```

AND I ALSO TRIED TO CREATE SCHEME LIKE BELOW
at first i have created an table in the database 
and then tried to run the schema by `php symfony doctrine:build-schema`
but it's throwing the error as below

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\neworangehrm\nohrm>php symfony doctrine:build-schema
>> doctrine  generating yaml schema from database


  Couldn't find class OhrmLocation


PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\
plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\symfony\plugi
ns\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\vendor\doctrine\Doctrine\Connection.php on line 1239.....
```